# Biztalk Developer pre-screening test and interview questions

Tags: xml, web-services, biztalk, middleware

Similar to other interview question threads, we're preparing to interview candidates for a Biztalk/.NET Webservices/XML/general mid-tier developer position, and I'm looking for some good input from the community. We'd like to pre-screen the applicants (since they'll come from a tech agency) with a written test that covers basic knowledge (I'm more interested in concepts than specific technical application - I don't want a test with specific technical questions that could be easily answered by using Google). Also, I'd be interested in any good interview questions related to those topics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) In XML Schema what is the preferred and why: elements or attributes?

2) What is the benefit of a targetnamespace declaration and what does it cost your document?

3) What is your favorite automated QA application/process and why is that one your favorite?

4) How could you use XPath expressions to increase automation processes associated with finding information in multiple documents?

5) What are common potential security vulnerabilities associated with xmlHttpRequest object and how would you write solutions to compensate for those vulnerabilities?

Comment: Since nobody else posted, you win by default!

Answer (score 2):

What can you do to increase performance of a BizTalk Application (i.e. how do you make it scale)?

-Krip

Answer (score 1):

"Why would you use Biztalk instead of any other middleware solution" - the point here is to show that they know a bit more about the domain in general, other systems and how they work rather than just be someone who's read a book on Biztalk.

Comment: I appreciate this angle - even if they would use something else besides Biztalk, it does show some domain knowledge instead of just memorizing facts about Biztalk. Thanks for the tip!